# Language switcher doesn't show all languages

Tags: multilingual

I made a multilangual site. I followed all the steps for plugins, components, assignments, etc. But, in the language switcher I see just one language.

I'm using Joomla version 3.7.2

How can I solve this?
Thank you so much.

[image: language switcher HTML]

Answer (score 4):

To create a multi-language website you need to:

- install and enable other languages
- enable language plug-in
- assign default menu item for each language
- create content languages for each language

Make sure that you have followed all of those steps

Answer (score 0):

I found the error following [this tutorial](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-configuration-multilanguage-site.html) and watching the image in step 23.
I have created the default item in the Italian menu for all languages.
So I created the default item in a different menu for all languages and set the default item for Italian language.